# memcpy issue when copying a pointer to a struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct, memcpy

I'm having trouble understanding why the 2 board pointers point to the same memory location, following is my situation in my game.c:

```
int game_state_transition(const struct state * s0, const struct move * m, struct state * s1) {
    memcpy(s1, s0, sizeof(struct state));
    memcpy(s1->board, s0->board, sizeof(struct move ***));
    if (game_update(s1, m)){
        printf("%p\n", s1->board);
        printf("%p\n", s0->board);
        game_print(s0);
        s1->next = s0;
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
```

and here's my game.h:

```
struct state {
    struct player * current_player;
    struct move *** board;
    enum game_status status;
    const struct state * next; };
```

I understand that after the first memcpy the 2 board pointers point to the same location in memory, but I do not understand the behavior of the second.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Ah, a three-star programmer.

Comment: `sizeof(struct move ***)` is the wrong size. However you just set `s1->board` to equal `s0->board` (with the first memcpy), so the second memcpy causes undefined behaviour since it has the same source and target. You haven't said what you are trying to do but I guess you are trying to make a copy of the board, instead of having one board with two pointers pointing to it?  (If so , update your question to include this info and also show how you allocate the board in the first place).

Comment: You also didn't say what behaviour you observed from the second memcpy (nor what you expected it to do).

Comment: Why ***wouldn't*** they point to the same location? Your program copies s0 to s1. You seem to be surprised that after copying s0 to s1, s0 and s1 contain the same values... even though that's the entire point of copying something, isn't it? ("values" includes values of pointers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First memcpy call makes what s1 points to, be the same as what points to s0. From this point s0->board and s1->board has the same pointer value

```
memcpy(s1, s0, sizeof(struct state));
```

example:

> before call:
>   s0->player = 0x000100
>   s0->move = 0x000200
>   s0->status = 1
>   s0->state = 0x000300
>
> s1->player = 0x000400
>   s1->move = 0x000500
>   s1->status = 2
>   s1->state = 0x000600
>
> after call:
>   s0->player = 0x000100
>   s0->move = 0x000200
>   s0->status = 1
>   s0->state = 0x000300
>
> s1->player = 0x000100
>   s1->move = 0x000200
>   s1->status = 1
>   s1->state = 0x000300

For the second memcpy there are more issues.

```
 memcpy(s1->board, s0->board, sizeof(struct move ***));
```

First of, you send the pointer, so the correct term would be sizeof(struct move **), but it will yield the same size, since all pointers have the same size.

If your intention is to make a new copy (in order to preserve the previous state), you would need to allocate memory first.

It is not often we see three stars in C programming, but it does happen. It all depends on the logic needed, and how many levels of changes should be possible in the call-stack. Most common is 1 and 2 (giving you the direct pointer, and a reference to a pointer that can be changed from an external point)